# Creating a portable MEX file that uses C libraries

Tags: c, matlab, mex

I have a MEX file that I compiled in order to run a C program in MATLAB.  The C code requires the MPFR library, which in turn requires the GMP library.  I linked against MPFR when I compiled the MEX file using the -L and -l flags.  It works like a charm on my system.  So far, so good.

Now, I want to distribute this whole setup to others.  As it stands now, in order to run my program on a new machine, one has to 1) install a C compiler, 2) install GMP, 3) install MPFR, 4) re-compile the MEX file and 5) pray that it works.  Yuck.

I would like to do one of two things: either 
1) Compile a single binary that already includes MPFR and GMP, rather than linking against them, or 
2) Write an installer script that will look for the compiler, GMP and MPFR on a new system, install them if necessary, and then finally compile the MEX file on any system.

I tried option 1 by just using the -I (that's a capital I) flag instead of -L and -l (lower-case L), but it doesn't work (I get undefined symbols errors for the MPFR library).

For option 2, I can't seem to find any instructions or tutorials for how to write an installer script.  Is this something that people do for MEX files?  I'm especially curious about what I would need to do to make an installer platform-independent, and whether there are any existing tools that simplify the process (rather than writing all of the code from scratch).

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Platform independent = compatible to all recent windows systems?

Comment: I'd look into CMake.

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, ideally I'd like it to work on Windows, Mac and Linux.  Right now I'm using Mac OS 10.8 and Matlab R2014a.  But even getting it to port easily to other Macs would be progress.

Comment: For option 1, I think you are referring to statically linking MPFR and GMP into your MEX file.  I've not used these libraries, but in general there is no reason you can't do this as long as they provide the ability to build static libraries.  The `-I` (capital i) just gets the declarations for the functions, but you still need the libs via (`-L` and `-l`).  Actually you can skip the lib switches and just list the actual static libraries (the file names!) at the end of the `mex` command and they will get linked in correctly.  The easiest way is to copy the libraries into the MEX source folder.